# Is it bad practice to type hint returned value on a function that must return true or false

Tags: php, cakephp, type-hinting

Quick question: For those who don't know CakePHP Model->count(); always returns an integer.

If I have a function to validate if a table is empty (returns true or false) would it be a bad idea to do this:

```
public function isEmpty() {
    return (boolean) $this->find('count');
}
```

As opposed to the more verbose:

```
public function isEmpty() {
    if (empty($this->find('count'))) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Basically, is it appropriate to use type hinting in this manner?

Comment: That's not type hinting, that's type casting. Casting to a boolean in PHP is `(bool)`.

Comment: Additionally, you cannot use `empty()` on a function/method expression.

Comment: Both are valid I prefer not to use shorthand.

Comment: And yes, I shortened it down for stack overflow but forgot about that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not type hinting - it's casting.  That syntax actually takes the value of the expression on the right, and *converts* it to the type you specify (in this case, that's `boolean`).

There's nothing wrong with using casting like this, as long as you're certain that it will have the effect you intend *for all possible values*.

Casting happens according to the rules outlined here:  [type casting](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php#language.types.typecasting).  You'll have to follow the links for whatever type(s) you care about.  The rules for [casting to boolean are here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php#language.types.boolean.casting).

Read the docs, make sure you understand them -- this can be tricky.  But it's a useful tool if you understand it and use it properly.

Comment: Thanks I wasn't sure if I was using the right terminology, I'll look over the docs that you pointed out.

Answer (score 5):

As Bolt said, that's a [cast](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php#language.types.typecasting), not a [hint](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.typehinting.php) (something quite different).    Also, you have it backwards.

But:

```
public function isEmpty() {
    return !$this->find('count');
}
```

would be fine.  You don't need a cast since the `!` handles it implicitly.

Comment: +1 As simple a trick as it gets. It would make more sense to use `empty()` but then I would have to make a local variable in order to use it and it's pretty pointless.

Comment: I would use `find('count') == 0` as the expression, just because it's a little more explicit/clear/meaningful to me.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you just check on what you want to know?

```
public function isEmpty() {
    return (0 == $this->find('count'));
}
```

But yes, I think your first version is appropriate in some sense.

Answer (score 0):

why not do this?

```
return (empty($this->find('count'))) ? true : false;
```

Comment: The other is shorter and sweeter but you can have an upvote for it. :)